# Internal energy of a gas under motion

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

Suppose, there a gas in a cylinder which itself is placed on a fast moving car, will there be any change in its internal energy due to the motion of the car? Do you think it may gain some kinetic energy due to increased motion of gas molecules as well?

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also consider the motion of the system, then you have to use a more sophisticated formalization of the thermodynamical system, proper of the *theory of continuum thermo-mechanics*.

There, the work done on the system is responsible for both thermodynamical effects (together with the heat entering the system) and macroscopic variations of the macroscopic kinetic energy (together with the work done by the internal stresses).

Macroscopic kinetic energy is **not** part of the (thermodynamic) internal energy.

Comment: So, I saw a Wikipedia page, as suggested by @TobiasFünke ... Also the answer by Valter, thus I got my answer: " It excludes the kinetic energy of motion of the system as a whole and the potential energy of position of the system as a whole, with respect to its surroundings and external force fields. It includes the thermal energy, i.e., the constituent particles' kinetic energies of motion relative to the motion of the system as a whole."